# Add additional details with queries and see them in AWS cloudwatch logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-rds, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a postgresql server on AWS RDS instance. All the queries that are executed on the instance is recorded in the AWS cloudwatch logs insights and I am able to filter them based on my needs.

Now going forward, I also want to log the sessionId of the users in the AWS cloudwatch logs insights.

For doing this, I tried to pass the sessionID as a comment to the sql queries hoping that AWS cloudwatch logs will also show the comments with the queries executing on the instance, but it didn't went intended and I am only seeing the query with no comments attached to it.

Is there any way I can pass sessionId with the queries so that AWS coludwatch log show it in the search.